# Error al relacionar tablas en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Veran quiero hacer con laravel 3 tablas: Plantas, User y Comentarios.
La historia es que un usuario pueda escribir comentarios sobre las plantas para hacer o contestar dudas sobre dicha planta.

Migración de la tabla Plantas:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePlantasTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('plantas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre'); // Nombre de la planta.
            $table->string('tamaño'); // Clasifica segun si es arbol, arbusto o hierba. 
            $table->string('flor'); // Si tiene o no flor.
            $table->string('hoja'); // Si es de hoja caduca o perenne.
            $table->text('descripcion'); // Caracteristicas del vegetal.
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('plantas');
    }
}
```

Migración de la tabla de usuarios:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Y la migración de la tabla de comentarios:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateComentariosTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('comentarios', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('usuario'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('planta'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('planta')->references('id')->on('plantas');
            $table->text('comentario');
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('comentarios');
    }
}
```

El codigo de index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Plantas") }} </h1>
        @forelse($planta as $plantas)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3><a href="plantas/{{ $plantas->id }}">{{ $plantas->nombre }}</a></h3>
                <span class="pull-right"> {{ __("Comentarios") }}: {{ $plantas->comentarios->count() }} </span>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#00AA00; color:#000000;" class="panel-body">
                <h4>{{ $plantas->descripcion }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <b>Tamaño:</b> {{ $plantas->tamaño }}<br>
                <b>Flor:</b> {{ $plantas->flor }}<br>
                <b>Hoja:</b> {{ $plantas->hoja }}
            </div>
        </div>
    @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ninguna planta en este momento") }}
        </div>
    @endforelse
    @if($planta->count())
    {{$planta->links()}}
    @endif
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Ahora mostrare la relaciones entre las tablas.

Plantas:

```
class plantas extends Model{
    protected $table = 'plantas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'descripcion',
    ];

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class);
    }
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class);
    }
}
```

Comentario:

```
class Comentario extends Model{
    protected $table = 'comentarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'planta', 'usuario', 'comentario',
    ];

    public function vegetal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(plantas::class, 'planta');
    }

    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario');
    }
}
```

Pero he aqui el resultado:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito: Aqui incluyo el contenido de web.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function (){
    $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Laravel');
    $crawler->filter('.result__title .result__a')->each(function ($node) { dump($node->text()); });

    return view('Welcome');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/', 'PlantasController@index');

Route::get('/plantas/{planta}', 'PlantasController@show');
```

Ademas, aqui traigo el controlador de Plantas:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\plantas;

class PlantasController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $planta = Plantas::paginate(5);
        return view('vegetal.index', compact('planta'));
    }

    public function show(Plantas $planta){
    $comentario = $planta->comentarios()->with(['usuario'])->paginate(2);
    return view('plantas.detail', compact('plantas','comentarios'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Te faltó incluir el código del controlador que está llamando a la vista.

Comment: @Shaz ya lo he incluido.

Comment: Creo que solo incluiste el listado de rutas, pero no el controlador o el código que esté llamando a dicha vista.

Comment: @Shaz he incluido el controlador de la tabla Plantas. User no tiene controlador (sera que es una tabla predeterminada en la BBDD) y por su parte el controlador de Comentarios esta vacio. A que igual ahí esta el fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para empezar tus nombres de clases, variables y objetos no coinciden con las convenciones típicas ampliamente sugeridas por Laravel, lo cual dificulta bastante entender el código y lo que pretendes hacer.

---

Los modelos deberían llamarse en singular y preferiblemente en el mismo idioma, además iniciar en mayúscula.

Puede ser en inglés:

- User
- Comment
- Plant

Pueden ser en español:

- Usuario
- Comentario
- Planta

---

Al obtener una colección de objetos (de plantas en este caso), la variable debería llamarse en plural, y por consiguiente, el foreach va a tener una sintaxis consistente:

En el controlador

```
$plantas = Plantas::paginate(5);
```

En la vista

```
@forelse($plantas as $planta)

    {{ $planta->nombre }}
```

---

Por último, no estás respetando del todo PSR-2, el cual es utilizado por Laravel.

---

En cuanto al error que te aparece, por lo que veo es simplemente que no definiste la llave foránea al definir la relación comentarios en el modelo de las plantas:

```
class Planta extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'plantas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
    ];

    public function comentarios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class, 'planta');
    }
}
```

Comment: Vale, con esto ya puedo ver la vista. Aun tengo otras dudas, pero las dejare en otras preguntas.